# Error in htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make sure that if HTTPS is used outside of the secure subdomain it gets redirected to HTTP.

This is what I have in the root .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect HTTPS requests for non-SSL pages back to HTTP. (Note that shared objects
# such as images are excluded from this rule)

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on

# my.EXAMPLE.com is the secure subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my.EXAMPLE.com [NC]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.EXAMPLE.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Put simply:

```
if HTTPS
if not in my.example.com
if NOT an image/css/js file
redirect to HTTP
```

But this is not working as expected, instead if I try to access a page outside of the my.example.com sub-directory via HTTPS I get a 404 Not Found error. Accessing the same page via HTTP has no problems, it works fine.

Any idea why this rule may not be working?

## EDIT

Here's the entire .htaccess file:

```
# Don't display .htacess files in directory listings.
IndexIgnore .htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Password protected for now
AuthType Basic
AuthName "EXAMPLE"
AuthUserFile "/home/EXAMPLE/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user

# Redirect HTTPS requests for non-SSL pages back to HTTP. (Note that shared objects
# such as images on both HTTP and HTTPS pages are excluded from this rule)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.EXAMPLE\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.EXAMPLE.com/$1 [R=301]


# Redirect non-www requests to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^EXAMPLE.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.EXAMPLE\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.EXAMPLE\.com\/$1" [R=301]

# Prevent direct access to the WHMCS folder must be accessed through secure subdomain
RedirectMatch 301 ^/WHMCS/(.*)$ https://my.EXAMPLE.com/$1

    
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Do you have other rules in you htaccess file?

Comment: I will update my question and include the entire htaccess file

Comment: What's the URL that you are going to that is giving you a 404, or does everything give you a 404?

Comment: http://www.example.com/file1.php - works, but https://www.example.com/file1.php gives a 404 error, when it should redirect to the first HTTP address instead since the file is not in the 'my' subdomain. HTTPS should ONLY be used inside the 'my' subdomain, and trying to use https outside of that subdomain should redirect you to the same file you were trying to access, only via http instead.

Comment: In my last comment the first url had http:// in front of it, and the second had https://

Comment: Is this htaccess file in your document root? And do you have a vhost for the SSL version of www.EXAMPLE.com?

Comment: SSL shouldn't be used on www.example.com at all anyways, and I want to redirect any requests using SSL on www.example.com to my.example.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.EXAMPLE\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.EXAMPLE.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: It still gave me a 404 error, even after removing other re-write rules and just leaving this one.

Comment: does your my.EXAMPLE.com and www.EXAMPLE.com point to the same location ? and the link in your browser does it change from my to www ?

Comment: www.example.com goes to the root folder on the server, the 'my' sub-domain actually points to a sub-folder.

Comment: then that explains why you are getting the 404, `my.example.com/folder/file.php` is not the same thing as `www.example.com/folder/file.php`

Comment: Right, but what I'm trying to do is redirect all HTTPS requests NOT IN my.example.com to HTTP instead. (http)example.com/file1.php - works, but (https)example.com/file1.php gives a 404 error, when it should redirect to the first HTTP address instead since the file is not in the 'my' subdomain. HTTPS should ONLY be used inside the 'my' subdomain, and trying to use https outside of that subdomain should redirect you to the same file you were trying to access, only via http instead.

Comment: ah yes yes, my mistake I forgot what exactly, then the 404 is not caused by that. So if you try to access `https://www.example.com/folder/file.php`, does it redirect you to `http://www.example.com/folder/file.php` (and you get a 404 error) ?

Comment: I get a 404, but no redirect.

Comment: Then you must setup a vhost configuration for your https www (see @jon lin answer)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you don't have an SSL vhost setup for `www.example.com`, and point its document root to the same place that the non-SSL vhost for `www.example.com` is, when someone goes to `https://www.example.com/`, your htaccess file is never read. I'm willing to bet that you need to put your HTTPS->HTTP rules in the htaccess file of your SSL vhost (where `my.example.com`'s document root is).

What you have seems to be:

```
http://www.example.com/ -> /home/EXAMPLE/ (or whatever your document root is)

https://my.example.com/ -> /home/EXAMPLE/subfolder/
```

So without a vhost setup for `https://www.example.com`, the htaccess file in `/home/EXAMPLE/` is never accessed when you go to the SSL example.com.

Comment: I'll have to look around in cPanel/WHM to see what I can find there, I may be able to make the vhost changes, but not sure.

Once I get time to check it out I will let you know if it worked.